# UnsatisfiedLinkError thrown while using native code for OpenCv on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I want to use OpenCV 2.4.0 native code in Android 2.3.3. For that, I used NDK release-8 to build `lib.so` shared libraries using the `ndk-build.cmd` script on Windows 7. I used Eclipse to create a project and build the .apk file.

Here's the problem, I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception thrown when I try to load the shared libraries using `System.loadLibrary(`) in the Java code. I have tried doing the same thing with the *hello-jni* sample in NDK, and it works absolutely fine.

I followed instructions on [this page](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html) for creating a project and for writing the `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` files.

Here's my java code:

```
package my.package.ocvtest1
// import android.foo.bar statements

public class OCVTest1 extends Activity
{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
        // code to display strings returned by native functions
    }

    public native String funtionName1();
    public native String functionName2();

    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("ocvtest1");
    }

}
```

Here's the `(Project dir)/jni/ocvtest1.c` file which implement native functions:

```
#include <jni.h>

// Other header files and some global variables

jstring Java_my_package_ocvtest1_OCVTest1 (JNIEnv *ptr, jobject obj)
{
    // code here
}

jstring Java_my_package_ocvtest1_OCVTest1_functionName2 (JNIEnv *ptr, jobject obj)
{
    // code here   
}

// End of file
```

I've googled this problem and tried the solutions, and even after implementing those solutions I get this exception. Here's all the things I've tried till now:

Used dynamic linking by copying the `libopencv_java.so` and the static `*.a` library files into the `(Project dir)/libs` and `(Project dir)/obj/local` folders and changed static block of java source code to

```
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
    System.loadLibrary("ocvtest");
}
```

Used static linking by adding `OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC` as below

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
include (<Path to Opencv.mk>)
```

Included header file generated by executing `javah.exe my.package.OCVTest1` in the command prompt while using dynamic linking.

Changed `armeabi-v7a` to `armeabi` for the abi version variable in `Application.mk` file.

For all the above changes, to make sure that the library files were loaded into the app's lib folder, I executed

```
adb push <path to library on disk> <path to /lib in app>
```

which copied the library files into the proper directory on the phone.

After trying all of this fixes, I'm still not able to resolve this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Used dynamic linking by copying the libopencv_java.so and the static
>   *.a library files into the (Project dir)/libs and (Project dir)/obj/local folders and changed static block of java source code to

You have to copy only `libopencv_java.so` (`*.a` file is not needed) to `(Project dir)/libs/armeabi-v7a`.

Also you have:

```
public native String funtionName1();
```

But in native c code there are only these functions:

```
jstring Java_my_package_ocvtest1_OCVTest1 (JNIEnv *ptr, jobject obj) // mistake?
jstring Java_my_package_ocvtest1_OCVTest1_functionName2 (JNIEnv *ptr, jobject obj)
```

It seems that name of the first function is wrong.

That should fix your problem.

Comment: I changed the name of the first function and then tried to run the app on the phone, still throws the unsatisfied link error exception. I've tried a lot of fixes mentioned elsewhere unsuccessfully. I've included the header file generated by javah, tried dynamic linking, made sure the libs are in the proper path in the phone.

Comment: Also, while trying static linking by adding the line `OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC` to Android.mk, the libraries are not built and instead I get seemingly endless compile time errors that I have to stop using Ctrl+C. Could this point to some discrepancy somewhere in the code? Also, I'm using Windows 7 and the android developers page for NDK says that it's not compatible with Windows 7. Is this the problem?

Comment: This is some of the gibberish output I was talking about:
(.text._Z25cvHaarDetectObjectsForROCPKvP23CvHaarClassifierCascadeP12CvM
emStomake: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libocvtest3.so] Error 3
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

Comment: @Shishir did you try to run opencv 3 sample?

Comment: I'm able to successfully build the libraries for Tutorial 3, but again I'm getting the unsatisfied link error exception when I run the app.

Comment: I got the app to work. I included the lines `OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on`
in the Android.mk file and used the function prototype generated by javah. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Shishir Yeah, removing `OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC` solved it for me... i.e., verbatim from <http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#native-c>